# Crear un nuevo Array con información de otros dos Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una aplicación hecha en React que debería comportarse de la siguiente forma: pinta una lista de ciudades y debería alertar las que tienen problemas, para lo primero se consume un `endpoint` que trae todas las ciudades posible y para el segundo punto se consume otro `endpoint` que trae solo las ciudades que tienen problemas. Hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema es que tengo la lista de ciudades en mi `state = { ciudades = [] }` y mi lista de ciudades con problemas en mi `state = { errores = [] }`. Mi `state ciudades[]` lo mapeo para pintar todas las ciudades y acá es el problema, como puedo conseguir otro **Array** basado en mi ***state ciudades y state errores*** con el que podre actualizar la lista de ciudades para que vayan cambiando de color.

```
state = {
  ciudades: [],
  errores: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
window.fetch('miurl_de_ciudades').then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then(jsonStr => {
      const { datum } = jsonStr
      this.setState({ciudades: datum})
    })
  } else {
    console.log('Respuesta de red OK.')
    //this.setState({servicesState: false})
  }
})
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message)
    //this.setState({servicesState: false})
  })

this.timerID = setInterval(
  () => this.handleSetInterval(),
  5000
)
}

handleSetInterval() {
window.fetch('miurl_de_errores').then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then(jsonStr => {
      const { datum } = jsonStr
      this.setState({errores: datum})
    })
  } else {
    console.log('Respuesta de red OK.')
    //this.setState({monitoring: [], isLoading: false, isError: true})
  }
})
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message)
    //this.setState({monitoring: [], isLoading: false, isError: true})
  })
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col s12">
      <div className="card">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Host</th>
                <th>Service</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Last Check</th>
                <th>Status Information</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.ciudades.map((ciudad) => (
                <tr key={watch.id}>
                  <td>
                    <span>{ciudad.attributes.name}</span>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClock} size="2x" className="right u-mr-1" />
                  </td>
                  <td>{watch.attributes.nameTwo}</td>
                  <td>
                    // aca deberia ir mi data de errores para poder pintar las filas o poder indicar que tiene un error con un icono.
                  </td>
                  <td>...</td>
                  <td>...</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

Intente crear un nuevo `Array` con un `Array.filter()` pero no me funciono, ya que me devolvía objetos vacíos...

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría lo siguiente, formaría un nuevo array de objetos, de manera que pueda tener la lista completa de ciudades y una propiedad que me indique si tiene problemas o no.

```
const listaTotal = [...];
const listaProblemas = [...];

const listaCiudades = listaTotal.map(ciudad => {
   const status = listaProblemas.includes(ciudad);
   return { ciudad, status }
})
```

De esta manera obtienes una lista de esta forma:

```
{
  ciudad: xxxxx,
  status: true / false 
}
```

Y ahora en tu código puedes facilmente saber qué status tiene la ciudad y personalizar el contenido.